# json works on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have the below part of code which works on my local machine but not on the server.

When I execute it on the server then am getting an error as **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"**

```
 <?php 
    $checkValue = array();
    $i= 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchdetails)) {

        $checkValue[$i][] = $row['ID'];
        $checkValue[$i][] = $row['1'];
        $checkValue[$i][] = $row['2'];
        $checkValue[$i][] = $row['3'];

        if(@$row['4'] == "NULL" || @$row['4'] == NULL) {
            $checkValue[$i][] =  "NULL";
        }else{
            $sql            = "SELECT * FROM Class WHERE ID_Class =".@$row['4'];
            $data           = mysql_query( $sql );
            $class = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
            $checkValue[$i][]  =  $class['Class'];
        }   
        if(@$row['5'] == "NULL" || @$row['5'] == NULL) {
            $checkValue[$i][]  = "NULL";
        }else{
            $sql            = "SELECT * FROM Place WHERE ID_Place =".@$row['5'];
            $data           = mysql_query( $sql );
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
                $checkValue[$i][]  = $row1['1'];
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
 ?>

 <script>
 var grid;
 var columns = [
{ id: "switch", name: "switch", field: "switch", formatter: imageFormatter, sortable: true },
{ id: "college", name: "college", field: "college", width: 50 },
{ id: "Number", name: "Number", field: "Number", width: 50 },
{ id: "Class", name: "Class", field: "Class",sortable: true },
{ id: "Place", name: "Place", field: "Place", width: 40 },
  ];

  $(function () {
  var MS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var data = [];
  **var listdata = <?php echo json_encode($checkValue);?>;**
  console.log(listdata);
  for (var i = 0; i < listdata.length; i++) {
  data[i] = {
    switch:  listdata[i][0],
    college: listdata[i]['1'],
    Number: listdata[i]['2'],
    Strength: listdata[i]['3'],
    Place: listdata[i]['4'],
  };  
  }
 })
  </script>
```

I tried this after searching for different answers in Stackoverflow

```
 var listdata = <?php echo json_encode($checkValue)?>;
```

but still it doesn't work.

What might be the issue thats stopping it here. Any help on this is much more appreciated!!

**EDIT: I identified the reason, The table class has some Spanish characters in it and so it is not displaying the data. How to** overcome with these characters?

Comment: are you getting data in `$checkValue` variable?

Comment: if you do a _var_dump($checkValue);_ what is the output?

Comment: `mysql_query` has been deprecated for ages now. time to upgrade to `pdo` or `mysqli`.

Comment: also, if you moved away from the error control operators, `@`, you might find more issues with your approach

Comment: @prakashtank, No, am not getting data in $checkValue

Comment: @AlexAndrei The Output of $checkValue is empty. I think that the data is not loaded into it!!

Comment: Can anyone help me out here please

Comment: @AlexAndrei described you should remove the `@` in the PHP parts to see possible error messages. Also note that `"NULL"` is not equal to `NULL` in PHP or Javascript (one being a string the other one being the null-type). Your script doesn't show how you connect to the database so make sure that happens before too